# codificacion utf8 con https no muestra caracteres latinos correctamente

Tags: php, html, jquery, utf-8

Estoy usando laravel con oracle ya tengo mi pagina publicada sobre https.
Cuando traigo datos con ajax me muestra los caracteres mal.

Entonces tengo que usar utf8_encode() de php para traerlos y poder imprimir.
Luego al querer imprimir la respuesta, aparecen los caracteres con acentos mal.

```
$result = array();
    foreach ($datos as $key => $dato) {

        array_push($result, 
            array(
                'localidad' => utf8_encode($dato->localidad),
                'descripcion' => utf8_encode($dato->descripcion),
                'oficina' => utf8_encode($dato->oficina),
                'cod_departamento' => utf8_encode($dato->cod_departamento)
            )
        );

}
return response()->json($result);
```

Comment: San LÃ¡zaro  (es raro! el content-type es utf8 , en mi localhost funciona bien, pero con https me da asi)

Comment: @Leoh estaria bien que pusieras el codigo del html, por si fuera de ahi.

Comment: @Leoh, has intentando convertir las cadenas a entidades `HTML` (`eg: `[`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.htmlentities.php)) en lugar de codificar a `utf8`?

Comment: si ya lo probe pero encontre la solucion.. convirtiendo los resultados con:  mb_convert_encoding($dato->descripcion, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8')

Comment: ¿Cual es el charset en la DB? ¿Cual es el charset en la conexion a la base de datos? ¿Cual es el charset en php? y finalmente, ¿Cual es el charset en la pagina?